# React dynamically add x amount of select boxes for filtering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, antd

I have an app that has various select box filters across different screens.
I'm populating the filters using json object which i'm passing down through components.

here is the link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ym5qyjj5jv

The problems i'm having are

1) i want to hook up state from page.js so i can set the value for each filter and then when the user clicks reset update that state. The main problem is getting the state as prop in searchbar.js

i have the state name in the json i'm using to generate the filters so i'm wanting to write this.props.[variable] but this doesn't work

2) Any other tips would be great

Comment: This (series of) question(s) is pretty broad for SO. Can you narrow it down to one particular question? And you should add your your code as a [mcve] so we don't have to leave the site to view it.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your comment, a lot of times people will ask for a working example outside of SO, I feel that gives a better overview of the code.

Comment: @Andy i've updated it to only have one issue, is the clearer for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, see the link in the question.

In page.js i passed the state (...this.state)

```
 <SearchBar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onReset={this.onReset}
          filters={filters}
          {...this.state}
        />
```

Then in searchBar.js when i'm looping through the filter json i can then get the prop

```
value={this.props[filter[1].name]}
```

If anyone else has a better way of doing this then let me know

Comment: Hello, can you share your solution in a code sandbox? I am having the same issue